# Enable HDMI port with Microsoft Basic Display Adapter

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, hdmi

I have an older laptop (Probook 4420s) with a Core i5 430m CPU and the integrated Intel HD Graphics. The laptop is updated to Windows 10x64 1803. It mostly runs well and has a lot of life left.

The exception is the video driver. Unfortunately, Intel does not provide a real graphics driver for this chip for anything later than Windows 7. Windows 8 and 10 are out of luck, except for the Microsoft Basic Display Adapter. It currently shows in the device manager as Intel 8.15.10.2900 from Nov 2012, but I've tried many other variants now and all them will only show the Microsoft driver from 2006 in the display properties.

Mostly, the basic software adapter meets my needs. But now I want to use this machine in a situation where I need the hdmi port.

Is it possible to get the basic display adapter to enable that port? Alternatively, is there a hack for installing a real Intel graphics driver for the i5 430m under Windows 10x64?

Comment: I have a laptop with i5-460M CPU running Windows 10 with the "default" 2012 driver that Windows Update installed. I haven't checked it in a while, but about 2 years ago the HDMI port was working fine with that driver. Are you sure it's driver's fault and not a hardware issue?

Comment: It worked when we first installed Win 10 in 2016, and stopped immediately. It's also been a theme with several other laptops I've worked on with unsupported graphics that the MS Display Adapter == no HDMI.

Comment: Worse comes to worst, could you use a USB to HDMI converter cable?